# Find the missing and duplicate elements in an array in linear time and constant space

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

You’re given an array of **N** 64 bit integers. N may be very large. You know that every integer 1..N appears once in the array, except there is one integer missing and one integer duplicated.

Write a linear time algorithm to find the missing and duplicated numbers. Further, your algorithm should run in small constant space and leave the array untouched.

Source: http://maxschireson.com/2011/04/23/want-a-job-working-on-mongodb-your-first-online-interview-is-in-this-post/

Comment: I think you'll find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-number

Comment: @JIm: Actually that is different. Here we get equations of the form  sum a^k - sum b^k = s, while that has sum a^k + sum b^k = s, allowing us to use Newtonian Identies. It does not seem obvious if we can use those Newtonian Identies here too. In fact, this seems more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249985/finding-missing-elements-in-an-array

Comment: @Moron: and that's why I said I thought he'd find it helpful, rather than voting to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Jim: I was saying that it might not be as helpful as one would think. Wasn't talking about dupe or anything. Anyway...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If all numbers were present in the array the sum would be `N(N+1)/2`.

Determine the actual sum by summing up all numbers in the array in O(n), let this be `Sum(Actual)`.

One number is missing, let this be `j` and one number is duplicated, let this be `k`. That means that

> Sum(Actual) = N(N+1)/2 + k - j

derived from that

> k = Sum(Actual) -N(N+1)/2  + j

Also we can calculate the sum of squares in the array, which would sum up to
n<sup>3</sup>/3 + n<sup>2</sup>/2 + n/6 if all numbers were present.

Now we can calculate the actual sum of squares in O(n), let this be `Sum(Actual Squares)`.

> Sum(Actual Squares) =n<sup>3</sup>/3 +
>   n<sup>2</sup>/2 + n/6 + k<sup>2</sup>
>   - j<sup>2</sup>

Now we have two equations with which we can determine `j` and `k`.

Comment: Nice analysis. I generalized it to m<N unknowns.

Comment: with 'N maybe very large', this needs bigInt support

Answer (score 31):

The XOR trick works in two passes with a read-only array.

This avoids the problem of possible integer overflows which the sum and sum of squares solution has.

Let the two numbers be `x` and `y`, one of which is the missing number and the other repeated.

XOR all the elements of the array, along with `1,2,...,N`.

The result is `w = x XOR y`.

Now since `x` and `y` are distinct, `w` is non-zero.

Pick any non-zero bit of `w`. `x` and `y` differ in this bit. Say the position of the bit is `k`.

Now consider a split of the array (and the numbers `1,2,...,N`) into two sets, based on whether the bit at position k is 0 or 1.

Now if we compute the XOR (separately) of the elements of the two sets, the result has to be `x` and `y`.

Since the criteria for splitting is just checking if a bit is set of not, we can compute the two XORs of the two sets by making another pass through the array and having two variables, each of which holds the XOR of the elements seen so far (and `1,2,...N`), for each set. At the end, when we are done, those two variables will hold `x` and `y`.

Related:

- [Finding missing elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249985/finding-missing-elements-in-an-array/5251995#5251995) which can be generalized to m appearing twice and m missing.
- [Find three numbers appeared only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003021/find-three-numbers-appeared-only-once/3010534#3010534) which is about three missing.

Comment: Is there a theory/ book write up which can elaborate about this?

Answer (score 6):

Using the basic idea from a [related interview question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-number) you could do:

- Sum up all the numbers (we shall call this `S1`) and their squares (`S2`)
- Compute the expected sum of the numbers, without modifications, i.e. `E1 = n*(n+1)/2` and `E2 = n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6`
- Now you know that `E1 - S1 = d - m` and `E2 - S2 = d^2 - m^2`, where `d` is the duplicated number and `m` the missing one.
- Solve this system of equations and you'll find that:

  ```
  m = 1/2 ((E2 - S2)/(E1 - S1) - (E1 - S1))
  d = 1/2 ((E2 - S2)/(E1 - S1) + (E1 - S1)) // or even simpler: d = m + (E1 - S1)
  ```

.

```
$S1 = $S2 = 0;
foreach ($nums as $num) {
    $S1 += $num;
    $S2 += $num * $num;
}

$D1 = $n * ($n + 1) / 2                - $S1;
$D2 = $n * ($n + 1) * (2 * $n + 1) / 6 - $S2;

$m = 1/2 * ($D2/$D1 - $D1);
$d = 1/2 * ($D2/$D1 + $D1);
```

Comment: Except it's not really `O(n)` if the numbers are `1..n` instead of `1..100`.

Comment: @IVlad: Why isn't it? Looping through `n` values is `O(n)` isn't it? And the other computations are `O(1)`.

Comment: @nikic - because the result of adding `n` 64-bit numbers is not necessarily a 64-bit number, so you need to write code to handle such big integers. That code will not run in constant time.  Squaring `n` is also not `O(1)` - notice that `n` has no upper limit. Not that your solution is wrong or anything - I don't think it's possible to do it under the OP's constraints, I'm just saying it's not linear.

Comment: @IVlad: I see no problem. You need a *constant* amount of 191 bits for the square sum and 128 bits for the normal sum.

Comment: @IVlad the act of adding or multipling (squaring) a 64 bit number is constant time. The result of such an operation is at most a 128 bit number, and the result of adding all possible 128 bit numbers together is at most a 256 bit number. There is a constant upperbound of a 256 bit number, and since the time it takes to operate on those numbers is related to the length of the numbers, for which there is a known upper bound, it is a constant operation.

Comment: I think you can eliminate the need for >64 bits entirely using modular arithmetic...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Java implementation based on @Aryabhatta 's idea:
Input:[3 1 2 5 3]
Output:[3, 4]

```
public ArrayList<Integer> repeatedNumber(final List<Integer> A) {
    ArrayList<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    int xor = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) {
        xor ^= A.get(i);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=A.size(); i++) {
        xor ^= i;
    }

    int setBit = xor & ~(xor-1);
    for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) {
        if((A.get(i) & setBit) != 0) {
            x ^= A.get(i);
        } else {
            y ^= A.get(i);
        }
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=A.size(); i++) {
        if((i & setBit) != 0) {
            x ^= i;
        } else {
            y ^= i;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) {
        if(A.get(i) == x) {
            ret.add(x);
            ret.add(y);
            return ret;
        } 

        if(A.get(i) == y) {
            ret.add(y);
            ret.add(x);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution proposed by BrokenGlass covers the case for two unknowns (corresponding to one duplicate number and one missing number), using two formulas:

[image: sum1]

and

[image: sum2]

The formulas yield the [generalized harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) of orders n of -1 and -2, respectively. (Power series)

This solution is generalizable for 3 unknowns by including the value of generalized harmonic number of order n of -3.

[image: sum3]

To solve for *m* unknowns (duplicates and missing numbers), use m generalized harmonic numbers of orders n of  -1 through -m.

---

Moron notes that this approach was discussed earlier in StackOverflow at [Easy interview question got harder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-number).

Comment: Harmonic numbers are of the form 1+ 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n.

Comment: @Moron  I'm referring to generalized harmonic numbers of negative orders. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers )

Comment: Those seem to be only defined only for m >= 1, but what you say makes sense. Here is another reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html. See equation 11.

Comment: @Moron The generalized harmonic number allows for m<0. Try running `Table[HarmonicNumber[10, -m], {m, 1, 7}]` in Mathematica. Or `Sum[p^k, {p, 1, n}]`.  Thanks for the link to PowerSum, which also seems to fit.

Comment: @David: I agree with you. It is well defined for all m. I misread the wiki page.

Comment: btw, your answer is lacking the use of using [Newton's Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) to form a polynomial whose roots we seek. Also, the generalization has already been treated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-number

Comment: @Moron Thanks. I'll make a reference to the earlier discussion you cited.

Comment: @David: Actually I just realized, Newton's identities don't directly apply... As we get equations of the form \sum (x_i)^k - \sum (y_i)^k = P_k. Groebner basis would be one way to go, or you can generalize my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249985/finding-missing-elements-in-an-array/5251995#5251995

Answer (score 3):

Taking the `leave the array untouched` requirement literally (i.e. the array can be temporarily modified as long as it does not change in the end), a programming-oriented solution can be suggested.

I assume that array size **N** is much smaller than **2^64** which is an utterly unrealistic amount of memory. So we can safely assume that `N < 2^P` such that `P << 64` (significantly smaller). In other words this means that **all** numbers in the array have some **high bits unused**. So let's just use the highest bit as a flag whether the index of that position has been seen in the array. The algorithm goes as follows:

```
 set HIGH = 2^63  // a number with only the highest bit set
 scan the array, for each number k do
   if array[k] < HIGH: array[k] = array[k] + HIGH // set the highest bit
   else: k is the duplicate
 for each i in 1..N do
   if array[i] < HIGH: i is missing
   else: array[i] = array[i] - HIGH // restore the original number
```

This is linear time and very little computation

Answer (score 1):

```
    long long int len = A.size();
    long long int sumOfN = (len * (len+1) ) /2, sumOfNsq = (len * (len +1) *(2*len +1) )/6;
    long long int missingNumber1=0, missingNumber2=0;

    for(int i=0;i<A.size(); i++){
       sumOfN -= (long long int)A[i];
       sumOfNsq -= (long long int)A[i]*(long long int)A[i];
    }

    missingno = (sumOfN + sumOfNsq/sumOfN)/2;
    reaptingNO = missingNumber1 - sumOfN;
```

Answer (score -2):

Psuedo code assuming the set is sorted

```
missing = nil
duplicate = nil

for i = 0, i < set.size - 1, i += 1
  if set[i] == set[i + 1]
    duplicate = set[i]
  else if((set[i] + 1) != set[i+1])
    missing = set[i] + 1
  if missing != nil && duplicate != nil
    break

return (missing, duplicate)
```

Comment: Almost certainly you *cannot* assume the array is sorted.