# Find repeating in O(n) and constant space

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy interview question got harder: given numbers 1..100, find the missing number(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe)
>   [Find the missing and duplicate elements in an array in linear time and constant space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766936/find-the-missing-and-duplicate-elements-in-an-array-in-linear-time-and-constant)

I saw an interesting Question on one forum.

you have 100 elements from 1 to 100 but byy mistake one of those number overlapped another by repeating itself.
E.g. 1,99,3,...,99,100
Array is not in sorted format , how to find the repeating number ?

I know Hash can do it O(n) time and O(n) space, I need O(1) space.

Comment: Why did you accept incorrect answer? (not O(1) space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it in O(n) and constant space:

1. For every element, calculate `index = Math.abs(a[i]) - 1`
2. Check the value at `index`

   - If it is positive, multiply by -1, i.e., make it negative.
   - if it is negative, return (`index+1`) as answer, as it means we have seen this index before.

""

```
static int findDup(int[] a){
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        int index = Math.abs(a[i]) - 1;
        if(a[index] < 0)
            return index+1;
        else
            a[index] = -1 * a[index];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: But what if the values in the array exceed the bounds of the array, e.g. 1000, 1001, 1002, 1000, ...

Comment: The question clearly said its 1 to 100 and one element is repeated.

Comment: Yup - I should read more carefully :/

Comment: @schtever yes this will NOT work for that but as user973931 said the question states clearly that numbers are 1 to 100.

Comment: You're storing a piece of information for (potentially) every element in your input. This is not constant space.

Comment: @Nick Do you understand what is space complexity? :)

Comment: @user973931 Sorry, meant to say "constant space", not "O(n) space" (edited).

Comment: @Nick Why you think its not constant space? I am using the same array for storing -ve sign

Comment: @Manan You're still using a linear amount of space to construct your solution. If your input set is immutable, or not randomly accessible, or doesn't support signed integers, then you'd need to create this array yourself.

Comment: @Nick The answer is applicable only with the constraints given in questions.....

Comment: @Manan None of these constraints (modifiable signed input with constant-time random access) was explicitly given in the question, so it's a bit of a stretch to assume them. But in any case, this still doesn't qualify as a constant-space algorithm. It's not a question of how many bytes you need to malloc(); it's a question of how many pieces of information you need to record.

Comment: @Elkamina thanks but I think the question clearly states that the numbers are b/w 1 to 100 and have exactly one overwritten by some other... I would appreciate if you can correct me where am I going wrong... Thanks again

Comment: @Manan Your solution requires storing n extra values (n=100 here), because you are storing index. That is not constant space solution.

Comment: @Elkamina I think you got me wrong I am not storing any index.. The index in the code above is a temporary variable.. For Clarity I have posted the code above

Comment: @Manan But you're still storing something. Your algorithm is basically a bucket sort. Your buckets in this case are the vacant sign bits in your input array. But it's still a linear-space algorithm.

Comment: @Manan The line `a[index] = -1 * a[index];` overwrites the input. This is why people are stating that this solution is not constant space.

Comment: @Elkamina, believe me if you run my code above the given example[5 5 3 2 1] will work.

Comment: @Manan My apologies. Yes, it does work. But, since you are mutating the array, it is still not a valid O(n) solution.

Comment: @Manan Let me give you an example where it won't work. Let us assume I am working on this weird 7 bit computer and the input is an array on 7 bits. Essentially, you are assuming that there is enough room to store one extra bit of information.

Comment: @Elkamina ok this will NOT work there... But do you think summation will work.. what if sum goes out of range? To add to it you are doing sum of squares too :)

Comment: @Manan You don't need to store multiple sums of multiple sum of squares. But just one instance of each. That is different than one extra bit for *every* number in the array. Anyways, see PengOne's solution below. Unarguably that is the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 24):

Calculate two sums: sum and square sum.

In your example:

```
sum = 1+99+3...+100

sq_sum = 1^2+99^2+3^2+...+100^2
```

Assume y replaced x in the sequence.

```
sum = n(n+1)/2 -y+x.
sq_sum = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 -x^2 +y^2
```

Now, solve for x & y.

Constant space and O(n) time.

### How to solve for x and y

From equation:

```
x = sum - n(n+1)/2 +y
```

Substitute this in the second equation:

```
sq_sum = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 -(sum - n(n+1)/2 +y)^2 +y^2
```

Note that y^2 cancels and you are left with a linear equation with only one unknown:y. Solve it!

Comment: This answer has 2 down votes and no comments. Please explain what is incorrect here so that the OP can rebut or revise and others understand the (potential) problem.

Comment: How do you solve this for x&y?

Comment: is square sum really needed, if the array length is 101 and there's 100 unique values, then you sum those 100 unique values and get 5050, the suppose the sum comes back as being 5149 you instantly know that 99 was duplicated, this doesn't work when there are more than one duplicates but the question only mentioned one value repeated once.

Comment: @Seph Array length is 100. One number is repeated, one number is omitted. Hence two unknowns, requiring two equations.

Comment: Why would anybody downvote a correct answer?

Comment: The space required for `sum` and `sq_sum` is dependent on the input size, i.e. not constant space

Answer (score 4):

New approach. Let `m` be the missing number and `r` be the repeated number. Passing through the array once, let `X` be the result of `XOR`ing the entries of the array along with the indices `1` to `n`. Then `X = m XOR r`. In particular, it isn't `0`. Let `b` be any nonzero bit of `X` (you only need to choose one, and one exists since `X` is not `0`). Passing through the array, let `Y` be the result of `XOR`ing the entries of the array and the indices `1` to `n` where the bit `b` is `0` and let `Z` be the result of `XOR`ing the entries of the array and the indices `1` to `n` where the bit `b` is `1`. Then `Y` and `Z` hold `m` and `r`, so all that remains is to make a final pass to see which is in the array.

Total space: 4 (or 3 if you reuse `X` for `b`)

Total time: 7 passes (or 3 if you do indices at the same time as the array and compute `Y` and `Z` at the same time.

Hence `O(1)` space and `O(n)` time.

Comment: Are you sure? In the first step slow is n+1. So array[slow] returns error or garbage, no?

Comment: I still think it wouldn't work. Consider cases where there are multiple cycles. Or consider a case where array[n]=n.

Comment: So you need one extra passes for each non-zero bit of X right? In that case your solution O(nlogn) in time. I am not very sure of that fact, but please let me know.

Comment: @ElKamina No, you only make one pass for your favorite nonzero bit. You do not have to do this for every nonzero bit. It works for any nonzero bit.

Comment: Does size of X depend on n? If yes, then it's not O(1) space.

Answer (score -1):

Calculate Sum of all integers
Calculate int p = sum % 100
100 - p is the answer

Comment: This will only give you the difference between the missing number and the duplicated one, but not enough to identify either of them. You've got two unknowns, you need to equations. See ElKamina's answer above.

Comment: That is incorrect. Take two cases: 5 is replaced by 10 and 6 is replaced by 11. In both cases sum is going to be the same.

Comment: example 1,99,3,4...100. Now sum % 100 will be 98. 100-98 is 2 :)

Comment: @topcoder Tell me how it works for the case where 5 is replaced with 20 ?

Comment: @topcoder I get 1+99+3+4+...+100 % 100 = 47.

Comment: @topcoder You've removed a 2 and added a 99. sum%100 will be 97.

Comment: @NickBarnes The sum of 1 to 100 modulo 100 is not 0. Why does everyone think that it is? 1+2+...+100 = 5050!!

Comment: @PengOne Oops, you're right... Forgot to divide n(n+1) by 2 :)