# Find a repeating element in an array in single for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm

Well hello there 
suppose you are given an array [1,5,3,6,7,3,67,54]
in which every element comes only once except one element which is 3 in this case. The task at hand is to find this element and you are allowed to only use one for loop which is equal to the size of the array.

PS:
you might suggest to use hash map but in that case after the traversal of array is over you would need to traverse the hash map to find which key has the value 2 which makes it 2 for loops and is not allowed.

How would you do it ?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far! Why would you need to iterate through the hash-map?

Comment: @KostasRim Sorting is at least as expensive as scanning an array, which makes your solution worse than 2 loops.

Comment: by the way this looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44637670/1632887

Comment: @chtz hello sir i was asked this in an interview and i used map from cpp to store the count of the numbers but interviewer said that would make it 2 loops ...same goes for using sets

Comment: @shourabh is there any space limit?

Comment: no extra space and only use 1 for loop

Answer (score 4):

Hash map can solve your problem. Actually, it has more than you need. Use an unordered_set. Traverse the array, if a value does not exist in the set insert it; otherwise you have found your duplicate value.

**--EDIT--**

Ok, one of us does not understand the other, that's for sure. Depending on what i understand from your question, below is a sample solution using a set. If you think i still misunderstand, then please give more details about your problem.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_set>

bool repeating(const std::vector<int> &vec, int &repeatingValue)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> set;
    for(auto x: vec)
    {
        if(set.count(x))
        {
            repeatingValue = x;
            return true;
        }
        set.insert(x);
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,5,3,6,7,3,67,54};

    int repeatingValue;
    if(repeating(v, repeatingValue))
        std::cout<<repeatingValue<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<"No repeating value detected!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please read the side note it says only use one for loop
if you check every time if the value is present in the set you are using another for loop to traverse the set

Comment: @shourabh you don't need to traverse twice. just check if a value exists in the set before you insert it.

Comment: tell me how you check if value exists ? By traversing all possible set elements right?

Comment: of course not! hash relates a key to an index. so checking means you just go to the index and look if the value is there

Comment: Probably what the interviewer is looking for, but depending on how the hash table is implemented there may be loops involved in handling collisions.

Comment: @user4581301 that's right. I did not claim that. I was just trying to fix a misunderstanding.

Comment: One other alternative, since there don't seem to be any other limitations in the question, you could skip the hash and make an infinitely large boolean array.

Comment: @seleciii44 i dont think you understand the problem i am presenting.. even if you manage to put map[3] = 2 in the hashmap , there will be other keys having values 1 like map[1] = 1 , map[5] = 1, map[6] = 1 etc, now to know which key has the value 2 you need to scan all the key value pairs this will account for another loop thats what i am trying to say