# Find the missing and duplicate elements in an array using XOR approach

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I was doing practice on search algorithms for arrays.

I had come across with problem of finding missing and duplicate element by using XOR approach for a given array of elements containing integer from 1 to n.
[Find the missing and duplicate elements in an array in linear time and constant space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766936/find-the-missing-and-duplicate-elements-in-an-array-in-linear-time-and-constant)
I am very well able to understand that how we can get the separate values of X and Y ( one is repeating and another is duplicate )

However I am unable to understand how are we able to decide that which one is repeating and which one duplicate.

( as per given solutions I could see xor result of XOR over list which has set-bit gives missing element and other list gives duplicate ).
However I am unable to understand the logic to reach on this decision.

Please help me to understand the logic behind this decision.

Comment: You can do another scan of the array and see which one of the numbers is the duplicate and which one is missing, doesn't change overall time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

While doing Xor operation, if number present even times Xor will be zero and if it presents an odd number of times then Xor will be that number.

Ex- xor of even freq number 5^5 or 3^3^3^3 will be zero.
Ex- xor of odd freq number 5^5^5^5^5=5 or 3^3^3=3 will be the same number.

If look closely you can see that finding a duplicate or missing both are referring to the same thing. Let's take an example and understand-
because if some number is missing it means a frequency of that number will be zero which is even number.
and if some integer is duplicate, it means a frequency of that number will be two which is even number and whenever you do Xor of the same number even number of times it will lead to zero

Ex- consider an dupArray(A)={1,2,3,5,5},missingArray(B)={1,2,3,4,_} range from 1 to 5
Actual array(C)={1,2,3,4,5}

A^C={5}

B^C={5}

Answer (score -1):

if you have found x & y then simply make a loop in existing array again and check if x doesn't exist in the array then the missing number is x otherwise it will be y.