# Find repeating and missing numbers in a given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, xor

For a given array A containing numbers from 1 to N, I want to find the pair of numbers (x,y) which is repeated and missing. Example A = [1, 3, 3] then x = 3 and y = 2.

While I know that this problem can be solved by taking the 
xor approach mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767648/5031518.
I am failing to understand the last part of the solution where the values of x and y are extracted from x ^ y by splitting the array based on a set bit.

It would be helpful if someone can explain me why the xor of two list results in the value of x and y respectively.

Answer (score 1):

At the first stage you calculate xor of values in full range `1..N` and in your list

```
1  2  3 .. x .. N  
1  2  3 ..   .. N  y
```

xor of all paired items gives 0, so result is `p = x xor y`

Value `p` is non-zero, but what bits are set? Those different in x and y.

So we can find any 1-bit from `p`, call it `mask`, and perform the same procedure on values 1..N and your list, choosing only values that have this bit set

```
for all v in 1..N and in list:   
   if ((v & mask) == mask):
       newxor ^= v
```

After all, `newxor` contains or `x` or `y` (all other items participating here are paired), and we can find another item with

```
 xy = p ^ newxor
```

Note: we cannont distinguish what item was repeated, and what was missed, just get pair of them.

For your example

```
p = 1^2^3^1^3^3 = 1 = 001 binary
```

repeating procedure with mask `001b` engages only odd numbers

```
 newxor = (1 xor 3) xor (1 xor 3 xor 3) = 3
```

and the rest number is

```
 3 xor 1 = 2
```

For example `(1,2,2)` we get the same `p`

```
p = 1^2^3^1^2^2 = 1 = 001 binary
```

and the same `newxor = 3` and the same rest value `xy=2`