# The Travel Tickets Problem

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting

> You are given a stack of travel tickets for various transportations that will take you from a point A to point B via several stops on the way. All of the tickets are out of order and you don't know where your journey starts, nor where it ends. Sort the tickets in the right order to complete your journey.
>
> ```
> tickets = [
>   {from: "Barcelona", to: "New York"}
>   {from: "Barcelona", to: "Gerona"},
>   {from: "Madrid",    to: "Barcelona"},
>   {from: "Gerona",    to: "Barcelona"}
> ]
> ```

I suppose, the right order is that one:

```
tickets = [
  {from: "Madrid",    to: "Barcelona"},
  {from: "Barcelona", to: "Gerona"},
  {from: "Gerona",    to: "Barcelona"},
  {from: "Barcelona", to: "New York"}
]
```

Because there is no ticket to Madrid, and no ticket from New York.

What would be the best algorithm for that task?

The language is JavaScript, but language-agnostic solution would be good enough.

> **Update:** I changed sample data to be not confused with [One-way flight trip problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991950/one-way-flight-trip-problem).

Comment: Must you go through all of the cities? Must you use all of the tickets?

Comment: Yes. Also, all tickets must be used.

Comment: Are you a lazy travel agent with too many tickets at hand? ;-)

Comment: Not exactly, it's job interview exercise.

Comment: There was something similar in this year's ICFP contest.

Comment: @NV, if it's a job interview, are you allowed to get outside help? I mean, you're the one who's applying for the job, right?

Comment: Probably easiest done by sorting the tickets after start time of the flight. Although that would sort of cheating ;)

Comment: @NV: why don't you add the `job-interview` and/or the `interview-questions` tags?

Comment: @IVlad, @NV : I have deleted that comment about dupe.

Comment: I actually voted for closing before I realized it's not the same question. Can't undo it.

Comment: I have voted to reopen. This is not the same question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can visit a node (a city) more than once, this is the [eulerian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

[Here](http://www.graph-magics.com/articles/euler.php) are two simple algorithms for solving it, depending on what type of graph you have. You have a recursive implementation on page 3 [here](http://roticv.rantx.com/book/Eulerianpathandcircuit.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just a doubly-linked list? Add each item to the list, linking each as appropriate; when you're done, you'll have two entries with unconnected links (one with nothing connected to its' "from" node, one without a connection at its' "to" node. These are the start- and end-points of the chain, and you read them out in sequence by starting with the entry lacking a "from" link, and following the link from one entry to the next.

Comment: That only holds if you're guaranteed that each City is visited at most once.

Comment: True - my suggestion is based on the example given, rather than accomodating further unspecified conditions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a directed graph from your tickets.
2. Find the node that has has indegree 0
3. Iterate over all nodes through graph edges to create your result

Update: With the added information in the original post, this solution does not solve the right problem. Look instead at IVLad's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101402/the-travel-tickets-problem/3101504#3101504).

Comment: Some questions: are you thinking of a topological sort? if so how do you use all the edges? if not, can you detail 3.? **how** do you iterate?

Comment: Is that them there fancy tech talk for "find city in `from` list that doesn't appear in `to` list, then start tracing your route"?  ;-)

Comment: @IVlad I might have been assuming too much from the sample data in the post, but if there are more than one ticket sharing the same source node, then yes it would require a topological sort which would make my step 3 much less obvious :-)

Comment: @scunliffe almost... I would probably build the directed graph using hashes giving me an O(n) solution instead of O(n^2) for a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got is a directed graph, and you wish to find an [Eulerian Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) in it. The linked article describes the algorithm for finding one, which is basically:

1. Find a City with fewer routes in than out (if there are none, start anywhere)
2. Travel by a ticket (edge) which won't leave the graph disconnected if it isn't there; unless no such ticket exists, in which case use that ticket.
3. Delete the ticket (edge) and repeat

You should end up having used all the tickets, and at the end destination.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a sample of the javascript implementation.

```
var un  =
[
 { from:'c',to:'d'},
 { from:'a',to:'b'},
 { from:'b',to:'c'},
 { from:'z',to:'a'},
 { from:'d',to:'m'},
]

function buildTable( un ){
return un.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex ){

//build the table.
    previousValue.from[currentValue['from']] = currentValue;
    previousValue.to[currentValue['to']] = currentValue;

//to find start and end.    
    if( !previousValue.from[currentValue['to']] )  previousValue.from[currentValue['to']]= false;
    if(!previousValue.to[currentValue['from']])  previousValue.to[currentValue['from']]= false;

    return previousValue;

},{to:{},from:{}} );


}

function getStart(nodes){
//find start node indx.
    for(var i  in nodes)
    if( !nodes[i] )return i;
}


function print(start,nodes ){


var sorted = [];
//while detecting false from buildTable structure.
    while(start){
        var  node = nodes[start];
        sorted.push(node)
        start = node['to'];
//console.log(start)
    }

return sorted;
}

var sorted = buildTable(un);
console.log(print(getStart(sorted.to),sorted.from));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There wouldn't be a ticket to a beginning destination. So at 1st I would find the beginning destination by comparing entries of "from" with entries of "to". So we get the 1st ticket
2. add 1st ticket to a new list (aka sortedList)
3. in a while loop add ticketList ticket where "from" equals to sortedList last ticket "to" until you get the same length of ticketList and sortedList

Here is the code in Dart for a similar task:

```
  Map<String, String> ticket1 = {'from': 'st_p','to':'msc'}; //1
  Map<String, String> ticket2 = {'from': 'izh','to':'sam'}; //3
  Map<String, String> ticket3 = {'from': 'kzn','to':'sch'}; //5
  Map<String, String> ticket4 = {'from': 'sam','to':'kzn'}; //4
  Map<String, String> ticket5 = {'from': 'msc','to':'izh'}; //2
  
  List<Map<String, String>> tickets = [ticket1,ticket2,ticket3,
                                       ticket4,ticket5];
  
  List<String> citiesFrom = [];
  List<String> citiesTo = [];
  
  for (var ticket in tickets) {
    citiesFrom.add(ticket['from']!);
    citiesTo.add(ticket['to']!);
  }
  
  String beginDestination = citiesFrom.firstWhere(
    (element) => !citiesTo.contains(element));
  
  List<Map> sortedTickets = [];
  
  sortedTickets.add(tickets.firstWhere(
    (element) => element['from']==beginDestination));
  
  while(sortedTickets.length != tickets.length) {
    sortedTickets.add(
      tickets.firstWhere(
        (element) => element['from']==sortedTickets.last['to'])
    );
  }
  
  print(sortedTickets);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    function fullPath(path) {
    let startingPoints = [];
    let endingPoints = [];
    let result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        startingPoints.push(path[i].from);
        endingPoints.push(path[i].to);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        if (!endingPoints.includes(path[i].from)) {
            result.push(path[i].from);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        if (startingPoints.includes(result[i])) {
            let indexOfPoint = startingPoints.indexOf(result[i]);
            result.push(endingPoints[indexOfPoint]);
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```